# How would I normalize this ket vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, vectors, normalization

So I am given the vector:

$$|Ψa⟩ = |x⟩ + |y⟩ − |z⟩$$

And I need to normalize it. I know that I have to take the dot product of the vector with itself (and it needs to equal 1) but how would I do this with a vector that is composed of other vectors (which I don't know the values of)?

Comment: how do you do it with $\vec r=\vec a+\vec b-\vec c$, which is a vector composed of other vectors?

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{equation}
|\phi \rangle = |x\rangle + | y \rangle - | z \rangle
\end{equation}
Then the normalized state $|\Psi\rangle$ satisfies $\langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle = 1$ and is given in terms of $|\phi\rangle$ by
\begin{equation}
|\Psi\rangle = \frac{|\phi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \phi | \phi \rangle }}
\end{equation}
In order to be more explicit, you need to know the inner products between $|x\rangle$, $|y\rangle$, and $|z\rangle$, for example $\langle x | x\rangle$, $\langle x | y \rangle$, and the combinations. If you don't know these inner products, then there isn't much more you can do to simplify the expression for $|\Psi\rangle$. I suppose you could write out $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle$ explicitly in terms of the unknown inner products if you wanted.

A common situation is that you expand $|\phi\rangle$ in an *orthonormal basis*. If $|x\rangle$, $|y\rangle$, and $|z\rangle$ form an orthonormal basis, then you do know all the inner products -- namely $\langle a | b \rangle = 1$ if $a=b$ and $0$ otherwise, where $a, b\in\{x, y, z\}$. In that case, you can compute $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle$ explicitly and get a numerical value you can plug into the formula for $|\Psi\rangle$ above.

Comment: So assuming |x⟩, |y⟩, and |z⟩ do form an orthonormal basis, what would I plug into the |Ψ⟩ formula?

Comment: @EvanDasami Let's say $|\phi\rangle=|u\rangle+|v\rangle$, where $u, v$ formed an orthnormal basis. Then you could expand $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle = \langle u | u \rangle + \langle u | v \rangle + \langle v | u \rangle + \langle v | v \rangle$ (hopefully that step is clear), and use $\langle u | u \rangle = \langle v | v \rangle = 1$ and $\langle u | v \rangle = \langle v | u \rangle = 0$. Once you have $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle$, just square root to get $\sqrt{\langle \phi | \phi \rangle}$. In your case you have slightly more algebra to do but it's the same idea.